# Is this a good behaviour of a both TCP and UDP program?

Tags: python, tcp, udp

I'm developping a client-server game in Python, and each quantum, the server has to send the state of the game to the clients.

I developed it with both UDP and TCP connections. UDP ensures the speed sending of the game states, and TCP is used for the reliability part.

Is this a good way of doing ?

So each quantum server sends data like this :

```
while playing:
    data = computeGameData()
    sendNewPlayUDP(data)
    sendNewPlayTCP(data)

    time.sleep(sleeptime)
```

I tested it, and it seems to work well, but I wonder if the thread can block because of TCP struggling. There is maybe a better way of doing.

Comment: As far as I know, a lot software are using both TCP and UDP.

Comment: Of course, but do they use it this way ? By sending every state by udp and tcp ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to :

http://gafferongames.com/networking-for-game-programmers/udp-vs-tcp/

you should not use TCP at all. This articles recommends using UDP and adding extra logic for the packets you absolutely want to be received and acknowledged. This article also states that TCP packets may interfere with UDP packets, increasing UDP packet loss rate.

You may also have a look to :

https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Source_Multiplayer_Networking

Loosing packets can be tolerated in many cases. It looks like a bit overkill to send the same data on both TCP and UDP channels.

Comment: I kinda agree. Sending data by both udp and tcp seems like it's the easy solution that eventually works. I changed this by adding some extra logic to my udp handler and it works much better.